# increase/decrease FontSize buttons for RadEditor control

Tags: telerik, radeditor

How could I implement **increase/decrease** FontSize  buttons for RadEditor control, the new font size should then be refreshed in the `<telerik:EditorTool Name="RealFontSize" />` button also included in the RadEditor Toolbar

[image: if Click in increase button, the realfontsize dropdown should increase in 1px as well as the font size of the selected text]

for example from the figure if Click in increase button, the realfontsize dropdown should increase in 1px to 17px as well as the font size of the selected text

**Update:**
Thanks to @rdmptn answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365866/432424 I got this first approach function, but I still don´t manage to get the current fontSize of selected text:

```
Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList["IncreaseFontSize"] = function (commandName, editor, args) 
{
    if (editor.getSelectionHtml() != "")
    {
        var selection = editor.getSelection();
        var theSelectedElement = selection.getParentElement();
        var currentFontSize = parseInt(theSelectedElement.style.fontSize);
        currentFontSize++;
        editor.fire("FontSize", { value: currentFontSize.toString() }); }); //fire the FontSize command
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please, select some text!");
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
};
```

**Update 2:** 
this function works well:

```
Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList["IncreaseFontSize"] = function (commandName, editor, args) 
{
    if (editor.getSelectionHtml() != "") 
    {
        var selection = editor.getSelection();
        var theSelectedElement = selection.getParentElement().firstElementChild;
        var currentFontSize = parseInt(theSelectedElement.size);
        currentFontSize++;
        var strNewFontSize = currentFontSize.toString();
        editor.fire("FontSize", { value: strNewFontSize }); //fire the FontSize command    
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please, select some text!");
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources on doing that:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/customtools/defaultcs.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-adding-your-own-buttons.html

The very first tool in the demo shows how to fire a fontSize change command. Use the selection and your logic to determine the current size and the desired size: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getselection.html.

Comment: very good links @rdmptn, could you please check my update to the question? I still don´t manage to get the current fontSize of selected text in order to increase it. many thanks.

Comment: question solved with the help of @rdmptn links, solution in **update 2** of the question.